# Cant Add WSL Interpreter to Intellij Idea 2018

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, windows-subsystem-for-linux, interpreter, intellij-idea-2018

I need to add WSL node interpreter to Intellij Idea(2018.2.2) but NodeJs(version 12.14.1) installed on WSL2 is not detected by Idea. I have installed Node with NVM on WSL2 and the distro is UBUNTU 20.04.1 LTS through Windows Store.

When I open the Settings/Preferences dialog (Ctrl+Alt+S), go to Languages and Frameworks | Node.js and NPM, and click the Browse button next to the Node Interpreter field the only interpreter visible is the Node interpreter installed in windows. I fI click "+" and say "Add" the only option available is "Local",
the "WSL" option is missing.

I tried re-installing NodeJs on WSL2 but no luck
I tried installing UBUNTU distro but no luck.

The Node Interpreter option is available if I install a higher version of Idea 2019.1.4 but My contractor doesn't have a license for the higher version.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Add WSL...** is there for me in 2018.2.8:

[image]

it should be available since 2018.2, see https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2018/06/webstorm-2018-2-eap-182-3208/

I'd suggest contacting support on this, providing your idea.log (**Help > Show Log in Explorer**)

Comment: Yesi contacted the support, they said the feature is available in version 2.18.3 onwards & the license for 2018.2 should work there.